# Setting Directory Access Control for large network size

Tags: c#, performance, permissions

We have a network path where we store all the folders/files. Now there are lots of folders and each has lots of files. If I try to grant permission at the root folder, it takes more than 48hrs to grant permission across each and every folder and file contained within. Below is the code I am using:

```
var myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\prdServerName\\trial");
var ObjectInheritRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("<User Id>", FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags., PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);

myDirectorySecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, ObjectInheritRule, out var modified);

myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

Now, in the above code, executing `myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl` takes long time to complete.

Can someone please suggest a better way to complete it faster?
Path `\\prdServerName\\trial` has lots of folder and each folders have many sub-folders and files.

Comment: I takes a long time because you may have circular links.  Also will run much quicker if you run from the local server instead remotely over a network

Comment: run the code on the server

Comment: Even if I run on the server it takes long time because the folder size is huge (around 100GB) with lots of sub-folders and files.